# Why .Net Framework 4.8 WPF app startup time is two times faster than dotnet core?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

So I've read about .net 7 performance improvements and I decided to try what is the improvement of the startup time of WPF app ran in net48 vs net6.0-windows and net7.0-windows. This is the test code https://github.com/ekalchev/WpfAppStartupTime

Results on my machines are
200ms for net48
430ms for net6 and net7

I tried to compile some heavy WPF app to see if what will be the difference. I took https://github.com/fluentribbon/Fluent.Ribbon and I can see about 200-300ms longer startup times in the net6 and net7. I wonder why after all the fuss with performance improvements the startup time is significantly slower. Can I do something to improve this?

Comment: https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2022/04/15/net-7-preview-3.aspx

Comment: It is also my experience. My fatclient .net 8 WPF App feels much slower than .NET 4.7.2. I could improve the really bad string.IndexOf performance (non english) by adding a project flag (https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/96221) but the overall perf. does not look good.